# Difference between functions with / without return Swift

Tags: swift, function

What is the fundamental difference between these 2 functions ?

```
func sqr(number: Int) {
    print (number * number)
}

func sqr1(number: Int) -> Int {
    return number * number
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is why I basically never teach `print` to new programmers. People conflate returning values with printing values, because ultimately they all get printed, so there's not much of an evident difference.

Suppose your goal was to evaluate a quadratic equation: `a*x^2 + b*x + c`.

How would you multiply the `x^2` term by `a` if it doesn't return a value?

```
func sqr1(number: Int) -> Int {
    return number * number
}

let a = 5
let b = 4
let c = 3
let x = 2
let y = 1

let result = a*sqr1(number: x) + b*x + c
print(result)
```

Trying doing this with `sqr(number:)`, and you'll quickly see that it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The first 1 is a `void` - return function that prints square of a number

The Second 1 is a `Int` - return function for a square number that returns it to caller

> As an illustration sometimes in coding you need to print a value for e.x debugging purposes for beginners sometimes they think it's useless but when you be an experienced you'll know reason of it unlike the 1 that returns the value to callers which makes more sense for all levels